# Angular mat-divider vertical width not adjusting

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to adjust the thickness of my `mat-divider` element in angular. My element is simply:

`<mat-divider vertical></mat-divider>`

and in my css I have used:

```
.mat-divider {
height: 40px;
border-right-width: 4px;
}
```

yet the divider is staying 1px thick. If I remove the `vertical` attribute, I am able to successfully adjust the width of the normal `mat-divider` element using `border-top-width` as expected, yet it doesn't work with the border right with. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I realized that if you use the selector `.mat-divider.mat-divider-vertical` you can access the border-right property as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--mat-divider-width: 18px;`

> style="
> --mat-divider-width: 18px;
> "

[image]